# Как можно сделать примерный поиск в списке наименований?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив со списком покупок например

```
['огурец','помидор','сыр','хлеб','молоко']
```

Как можно получить из массива все значения которые слегка попдают под результаты поиска (как в поисковике гугл)?

пишу в поиске первую букву, и он мне вернул все значения которые подходят под мой запрос (например пишу букву о, вернулось слово огурец).

По идее это можно сделать с помощью метода filter но он работает только с цельными названиями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично мне нравится такой вариант, довольно простой и понятный:

```js
let words = ['огурец','помидор','сыр','хлеб','молоко']

i.addEventListener('input', () => {
  console.log(words.filter(e => e.toLowerCase().includes(i.value)))
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="i">
```

Если сравнивать с ответом от @АлексейШиманский, то к примеру если написать `o` в запрос, то у меня найдётся также молоко, т.к. идёт проверка есть ли в словах написанное значение, тогда как у Алексея, идёт проверка на "начинается ли на", в поддержку его ответа, у него всё работает быстрее.

Comment: const words = ...

Comment: @Jackson `const` в данном случае не лучший выбор т.к. слова могут динамически подгружаться в массив с сервера или это вообще может быть пользовательский массив, данные в котором назначает пользователь, тогда тем более `const` не нужно ставить.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = ['огурец','огурод', 'помидор','сыр','хлеб','молоко'];

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('input', ({target}) => {    
    let filteredData = data.filter(el => el.substring(0, target.value.length) === target.value.toLowerCase());
    console.log(filteredData.join(','));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

Тут смотрится совпадение именно с начала слова. Если нужно искать вхождение подстроки в строку независимо от позиции, то вместо `substring` можно использовать **[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)**

Comment: Можно и просто `indexOf`-ом поискать, чтобы не работать с подстрокой, а `includes` будет лишний раз проверять что передали строку или регулярное выражение

Comment: Не хватает `toLowerCase()` как по мне.

Comment: @ΝNL993 да. Можно.